# Wagtail 4 FieldPanel issue with ForeignKey

Tags: django, wagtail

I have the following setup in wagtail 4.0.4:

```
@register_snippet
class Copyright(models.Model):
   class CopyrightType(models.TextChoices):
      PH1 = "PH1", _("Phase 1")
      PH2 = "PH2", _("Phase 2")

   type = models.CharField(
       max_length=3,
       choices=CopyrightType.choices,
       unique=True,
       )

class ReportPage(Page):
    copyright = models.ForeignKey(
        Copyright,
        to_field="type",
        default="PH2",
        on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT,
    )
```

Now the set up works just fine. But if I add the FieldPanel:

```
class ReportPage(Page):
    copyright = models.ForeignKey(
        Copyright,
        to_field="type",
        default="PH2",
        on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT,
    )

    promote_panels = Page.promote_panels + [
        FieldPanel("copyright"),
    ]
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'PH2'.
```

Is there any way to tell the FieldPanel to look at the field referenced in the "to_field" option instead of the primary key?

Comment: Do you mind my asking why you are setting things up this way? I kind of like the idea of the ForeignKey using a more human readable field on the related model. But it looks to me like defining CopyrightType the way you are doing it means you will need to do a deploy to change the members of the Copyright class which to me loses the flexibility one gains by putting that model in the database.

Comment: @cnk I don't think the foreign key approach is the problem here. The fk relationship works as expected. And I like having the option to easily identify the default option. I am afraid that the FieldPanel has no handle to use another field as a foreign key but the default id and my only option would be to fall back to your suggestion.

Comment: Yes the error message appears to indicate FieldPanel expects the default Django behavior of foreign keys creating a numeric <somemodel>_id column. Your other option would be to allow the ReportPage to use the Copyright id column for its relationship.